# Background-image + Fixed + NOT Transparent

Tags: html, css

This is my css:

```
body {
  background-image: url('mybackground.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: 100%;
}
```

But when I scroll down, the background image is transparent & this is not what I want.(my background image is like a header image, just like this website but the header if fixed).
What should I do? 
Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by transparent?  Can you show as JSFIDDLE  Here is what your code gives me https://jsfiddle.net/hhfk2766/

Comment: @Trapline by transparent i mean that when I scroll down, the header image will come under every text in the page.

Comment: @SLY: So what you want is your header to be on top of everything?

Comment: @Snorlax - yes of course... i want it to be fixed & NOT to be transparent

Comment: @SLY Is this what you want [Fiddle link here](http://jsfiddle.net/2ubdmL8g/)

Comment: @Malik - No...i want to apply the code only to body, no class & no id.

Comment: @Malik go check [fhoke](http://www.fhoke.com).see the header?just like that.

Comment: When you put in the CSS for body you are assigning attributes to the body class. But you just want to stick an image at the top so make that 1 image fixed not the whole body. putting your header image in a header div and giving it a header ID or class will allow you to assign attributes to just that element which will give you more flexibility when coding in the future and will cause you a lot less problems going forward.

Comment: @SLY they didn't use background image they used header html tag....

Comment: @SLY You can make background image fixed but you can't add `z-index` to it .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This time it is better explained:

You need header element, with position fixed:

```
<header style="position: fixed;"> ... </header>
```

Try the JSFiddle link [here](http://jsfiddle.net/x3zq035y/5/)

.

Best of luck.

(Mark this as answer if this serves your need)

Comment: You have'nt fully understood what i'm trying to do...i want my website's header to look exactly like this websites header...the only difference is that i want my header to stay fixed when i scroll down.just like [Quora](http://quora.com)

Comment: Nope...nothing again...it's the same.

Comment: Well I can see it is like Quora. Did you also remove background-attachment: fixed;  ?

Comment: Yes I did...let me explain a little more to you...see the header on this website?the place where you can search and see your profile and whatever?i want my website to be the same...the only difference is that i want mine to be `fixed`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83474/discussion-between-pgmreddy-and-sly).

Answer (score 0):

What I would suggest is using a fixed div at the top of the page that the content can scroll behind.  You can remove the background code.  this way you have more options and can still add background texture if you like. Otherwise you are applying position FIXED to the whole body which you dont want to do you want to apply fixed to 1 image element.   Please Check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1m56at2y/)

I would also read [this article](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) to read more on the layout position properties.

```
    .header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;

}

<div class="header"><img src="mybackground.jpg"></div>
```

Comment: You have'nt fully understood what i'm trying to do...i want my website's header to look exactly like this websites header...the only difference is that i want my header to stay fixed when i scroll down.just like [Quora](http://quora.com)

Comment: You're using a class, i want to apply my code to `body` not a class.

Comment: If you look Quora uses div.siteheader not body.